# There is an error on my DevComponents.Dotnetbars.Controls, which they don't placed on the form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I drag and drop or double click my `DevComponents.Dotnetbars.Controls`, they placed under the form instead of on form, for solving this problem I cleaned solution and my program then rebuilt them but my problem hasn't been solved,  My environment is visual studio 2015.

In this form the `buttonX1` control placed under the form

[image]